# Combine Subset & Unique in R

Tags: r, coding-efficiency

Is there a way to combine these 2 different R statements to make it a bit cleaner?

```
x6 <- subset(dBase, dBase$Operation_Name == "Wash")
x7 <- unique(x6$machine_number)
```

This works but was wondering if it's possible to put this into one line going forward.

**The goal** is to get the unique `machine_number` where the `Operation_Name == "Wash"`

Thanks!

Comment: `unique(dBase[dBase$Operation_Name == "Wash", "machine_number"])` will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unique(dBase[dbase$Operation_Name=="Wash",]$machine_number)`

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
df <- data.frame(Operation_Name = c("Wash", "Fold", "Rince"),
                 machine_number = c(42, 43, 44))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(Operation_Name == "Wash") %>%
  pull(machine_number)
# [1] 42
```